# firefox addon: simple example using Request API (ajax call to local file). Unable to implement the one given in the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

```
    var Request = require("request").Request;
 var latestTweetRequest = Request({
  url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json",
  onComplete: function (response) {
 var tweet = response.json[0];
console.log("User: " + tweet.user.screen_name);
console.log("Tweet: " + tweet.text);
  }
});

// Be a good consumer and check for rate limiting before doing more.
Request({
  url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json",
  onComplete: function (response) {
    if (response.json.remaining_hits) {
  latestTweetRequest.get();
} else {
  console.log("You have been rate limited!");
}
}
}).get();
```

The above is the sample code given in this page . https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html . What I know is :

Simple case :
We have main.js and script.js . We usually write API(SDK) related things in main.js and our normal javascript in script.js . I have tried copying the above code to main.js but didnt work .

Requirement : Simple example containing main.js and script.js showing the usage of ajax call with a local file . For example, please upload samplefile.txt with some text saved in it to the 'data' directory  and do some ajax call and get the data from the file. Thats it .

Comment: The example doesn't work because the Twitter API has changed.

Comment: I dont want twitter api to work, just want the ajax call of local file to work .

Comment: Then post your code, without it it's difficult to tell what the issue might be.